# Faster way to render XML (10MB) file, loop the content and display output

Tags: php, performance, xml, file

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.example.com/example.xml");
            //echo "<pre>";
            //print_r($xml);
            $cnt =0;
            $customereview='';
            foreach($xml->comment as $comment){
                    if($comment->ProdNid == $productID){
                        if($comment->PostedOn != '' && $comment->PostedBy != '' && $comment->comment_text != ''){
                            if($cnt < 5) { 
                            $cnt++;         
                            $customereview.="<div class='review_wrp'><span class='review_product'>".$title."</span><span class='review'>".(string)$comment->comment_text."</span><span class='review_person'>".(string)$comment->PostedBy.",".(string)$comment->PostedOn ."</span>
                        </div>";
                                if($cnt==5)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        }//end of if
                    }
                }

                echo $customereview;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no error handling.  Loading a remote resource is somewhat likely to fail.  Unfortunately, simplexml [doesn't make error-handling easy](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php).

Instead of filtering the XML using PHP code, I suggest selecting exactly the nodes you want using an [XPath query](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).  The XPath library is more likely to be optimized than your PHP code.  In any case, it is certainly simpler to maintain one string describing the relevant nodes than a bunch of nested PHP statements.

I've chosen to use PHP templating for rendering, as it is easier to see that it is output.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/example.xml');
foreach ($xml->xpath("//comment[ProdNid = '" . htmlspecialchars($productId) .
                     "'][PostedOn][PostedBy][comment_text][position() <= 5]") as $comment) {
?>
    <div class='review_wrp'>
      <span class='review_product'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title);
      ?></span><span class='review'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment->comment_text);
      ?></span><span class='review_person'><?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment->PostedBy);
      ?>,<?php echo htmlspecialchars($comment->PostedOn); ?></span>
    </div>
<?
}
```

All of those output strings probably need to be escaped to prevent, for example, cross-site scripting.  I've used [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) for that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer response. but it is not loading fast as i have to read 10 mb Xml file.

Comment: sachin, do you need code to download 10Mb files faster or code to parse the XML faster? The code posted by @200_success is faster than your version at parsing and displaying. You should accept his answer. You never mentioned in your question the network/download penalty.